# Import from incremental backups to a new host in Oracle 11g

Tags: backup, oracle-11g-r2, import

I am using Oracle 11g. I would like to know that whether it is possible to import from incremental level 0 & 1 backups to a new host using RMAN. If yes, how can I do that?

For level 1 I am using differential method.

Answer (score 0):

yes, oracle can do that provided there is a full backup available to start the restore with. When that is restored you can recover the incremental backups against the restored database. When the incrementals were done online (mostly the case, you also need the archived log files)